# Sort List by custom order

Tags: list, flutter, sorting, dart

Give a List, for example

```
[{id: 4}, {id: 5}, {id: 4}, {id: 7}, {id: 6}, {id: 4}, {id: 5}, {id: 7}]
```

And given another list

```
[5, 7, 6, 4]
```

How do I sort the first list based on the values of the second?

(That is, obtain

```
[{id: 5}, {id: 5}, {id: 7}, {id: 7}, {id: 6}, {id: 4}, {id: 4}, {id: 4}]
```

as the result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first would build an inverse map that maps ID values to lists of all entries with that ID.  From there it'd be straightforward to just iterate over the second list that specifies the desired order, lookup the entries from the inverse map, and splice together the results:

```dart
void main() {
  var items = <Map<String, int>>[
    {'id': 4},
    {'id': 5},
    {'id': 4},
    {'id': 7},
    {'id': 6},
    {'id': 4},
    {'id': 5},
    {'id': 7},
  ];

  var orderBy = [5, 7, 6, 4];

  var idToItems = <int, List<Map<String, int>>>{};
  for (var item in items) {
    (idToItems[item['id']] ??= []).add(item);
  }
  
  var sorted = <Map<String, int>>[
    for (var id in orderBy)
      ...idToItems[id],
  ];
  
  print(sorted);
}
```

This approach is a bit more complicated, but it should have a time complexity of O(m + n) (where m is the length of `items` and n is the length `orderBy`):

- Building the inverse map (`idToItems`) takes O(m) time.  For each of the m elements of `items`:

  - Do a lookup or insert in `idToItems`, which is O(1).
  - Append the entry to the list of entries with the same ID, which should be O(1) amortized.
- Iterating over `orderBy` is O(n).
- Splicing the sublists together overall would be O(m).

Answer (score 3):

You may try something like this :

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = [
    {"id": 4},
    {"id": 5},
    {"id": 4},
    {"id": 7},
    {"id": 6},
    {"id": 4},
    {"id": 5},
    {"id": 7}
  ];

  List<int> orderBy = [5, 7, 6, 4];

  List sorted = [];

    orderBy.forEach((val) => list
      .forEach((ele) => ele.values.first == val ? sorted.add(ele) : ""));

  
  print(sorted);
}
```

Comment: This is nice and compact, but is not as time efficient as it could be.  This is O(m * n), where m is the length of the list to be sorted and n is the length of the list to sort by.  That might be good enough, but this could also be done in O(m + n) time (at the expense of more space), which could matter if the lists are very large.

Comment: I am going to change the accepted answer, since I am using @jamesdlin answer, I hope it's ok